# Rails running on WEBrick with HTTP authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick

How to set up HTTP authentication in a Rails application running on WEBrick?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238272/ruby-webrick-http-authentication

Comment: No it's not. I'm not using Webrick through ruby code, but through a rails application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails has a built in method for adding [http basic authentication](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html).

You should also look at something like [Authlogic](http://ttp://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) for authentication and user session management.